# Using python to modify a cell value gives "Data Validation extension is not supported and will be removed warn(msg)"

Tags: python, openpyxl

The following is my python code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import openpyxl

# This is the code
log = 'G:\Data\Hotels\Hotel.txt'  #text file with list of hotel
file = open(log, 'r')
hotels = []
line = file.readlines()
for a in line:
    hotels.append(a.rstrip('\n'))

# We'll use this list to keep track of all filepaths
filepaths = []

for hotel in hotels :
    fp = "G:\\Data\\Hotels\\"+hotel+"\\"+hotel+" - Meetings\\"+hotel+"_Action_Log.xlsx"
    filepaths.append(fp)


for filepath in filepaths:
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename = filepath, data_only = True)
    ws = wb.worksheets[1]
    ws['B2'] = 'hotel'
    wb.save
```

My code takes a text file with the list of hotels and uses this list to loop through all the relevant hotel files and then for all these hotel files I want to change the value of the cell B2 to the hotel name.

However, I am not sure if this is the correct way to do with as I am new to Python and I'm also getting the message

C:\Python34\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\worksheet.py:319: UserWarning: Data Validation extension is not supported and will be removed
  warn(msg)

Comment: Ignoring the warning for now, what's your problem with your approach? Error, unexpected result? If error, please show the traceback; if unexpected result, please show us what you got and what's your expected output.

Comment: @YilunZhang The problem is that I want to change the contents of the cell 'B2' of each file to the specific name of that hotel and I get the warning message and nothing happens to the cell B2 of my files. However, if I delete from 'for filepath in..' and run the code I get no warning message

Answer (score 0):

Try `ws['B2'].value = 'hotel'`.